# What is the difference between Dim and Public?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

A question about scope was raised today and it got me thinking.

I've always understood VBScript scope and how to declare Globally and Locally. It occurred to me though that I never use `Public` variables but tend to use `Dim` instead when declaring Globally.

As far as I understood it `Dim` is the same as `Public`, but if that's the case why have both of them? Is there a difference between the two and is it good practice to use one over the other?

---

> **Update:**
>
> This question is aimed purely at VBScript, not VBA and especially in the context of Classic ASP.
>
> - [Key Differences Between Visual Basic for Applications and VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx)

Comment: @duDE I did see that but it is specifically for [tag:vba] not [tag:vbscript] and by extension [tag:asp-classic].

Comment: Is the VBA and VBS not the same - I thought the VBS is a subset of VBA or am I wrong?

Comment: @duDE They are both VB but they have their differences. VBA supports strongly typed variables where as VBScript being a scripting language does not all variables are `variant` data type. See [Key Differences Between Visual Basic for Applications and VBScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Access restrictions make sense in modular or object-orientated languages. As Basic started as a simple procedural language, the later addition of such features make strict rules for using Dim, Public, and Private difficult.

**Everything below is about VBScript (not VBA, not ASP, not VB.NET)**

Facts:

1. In out of Sub/Function/Class code, Dim, Public, and Private are equivalent: All declarations apply to the global scope
2. In Subs/Functions/Methods you can use Dim only. The declarations apply to the Func/Sub/Method-local scope
3. In class definitions, Dim **and** Public declare variables that are accessible for out-of-classe code; Private creates variables that can be accessed from class-code only. Private methods are callable from class-code only, Public methods (default) can be called from 'outer space'.

Ruleset I:

1. Use Dim for top-level declarations, because Public/Private have no discernible effect
2. Use Dim **in** Subs/Functions/Method, because you must
3. Use Public or Private (but not Dim) for member variable declarations, because the access permissions are important
4. Use Private for private methods, but don't bother with Public, because it's the default

Sample code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim     gsDim  : gsDim  = "gsDim"
Public  gsPub  : gsPub  = "gsPub"
Private gsPriv : gsPriv = "gsPriv"

Class cX
  Dim     m_sDim
  Public  m_sPub
  Private m_sPriv
  Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_sDim  = "m_sDim"
    m_sPub  = "m_sPub"
    m_sPriv = "m_sPriv"
  End Sub
  Function ToString()
    ' Public Whatever => syntax error
    ' Private Whatever => syntax error
    Dim Whatever ' => no problem to use Dim for local declaration
    ToString = ToStringPriv()
  End Function
  Private Function ToStringPriv()
    ToStringPriv = Join(Array(m_sDim, m_sPub, m_sPriv))
  End Function
End Class

Function main()
  ' Public Whatever => syntax error
  ' Private Whatever => syntax error
  Dim Whatever ' => no problem to use Dim for local declaration
  main = 0
  WScript.Echo "in func main():", Join(Array(gsDim, gsPub, gsPriv))
  Execute "WScript.Echo ""via Execute:"", Join(Array(gsDim, gsPub, gsPriv))"
  Dim oX : Set oX = New cX
  WScript.Echo "oX.ToString():", oX.ToString()
  Dim s
 On Error Resume Next
  s = oX.ToStringPriv()
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
  s = oX.m_sPriv
  WScript.Echo Err.Description
 On Error GoTo 0
End Function

WScript.Echo "top level code:", Join(Array(gsDim, gsPub, gsPriv))
WScript.Quit main()
```

output:

```
cscript dimpubpriv.vbs
top level code: gsDim gsPub gsPriv
in func main(): gsDim gsPub gsPriv
via Execute: gsDim gsPub gsPriv
oX.ToString(): m_sDim m_sPub m_sPriv
Object doesn't support this property or method
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

**Update wrt Kul-Tigin's comment:**

Ruleset II (when writing code for a host that supports modules):

1. Treat modules as classes, i.e. apply I.3 and I.4 to your top-level variable rsp. Sub/Function declarations (because now access rights matter/are enforced)

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Public  gsPub   : gsPub = "gsPub"
Private gsPriv  : gsPriv = "gsPriv"

Class AContext
    Public CodeObject
End Class

With (New AContext)
    Set .CodeObject = Me
    WScript.Echo .CodeObject.gsPub
    WScript.Echo .CodeObject.gsPriv
End With
```

Evidence:

```
cscript dimpubpriv.vbs
gsPub
... Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'CodeObject.gsPriv''
```

Comment: Super Answer Ekkehard, you've confirmed what I already knew which is great. Thanks. +1

Comment: +1 but sometimes you may need to access a global member from another scope. Since private members defined in global scope are not accessible from an external invoker like a Com Object Facts #1 and Ruleset I #1 may be a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks for the update!
Since `ScriptControl` is 32-bit only component, thought that some people may encounter problems while testing the case.
So I've updated the answer with a component-free code for the same job.

Comment: `Public/Private` _does_ matter in VBScript when the script/module is used by other languages. For example, JScript code in a WSF file will not be able to call a VBScript sub/function defined as `Private` within an included `VBS` file.