# Calling a sub() to get variable values in ASP/VBscript

Tags: function, vbscript, asp-classic

This might be an elementary question... But its got me stumped.

At the beginning of an ASP/VBscript page, I am calling a `sub()` to get some config values of the application. I am using a `sub` so that I do not need to write the same query on each page of the application to get these values. This `sub` is included within a file which is being `#included` at the top of each page.

I have tested and have confirmed that within the `sub()` the config variables have correct and valid values.
But when I try call these variable values later in the page, they are empty.

Is there some kind of permission setting on the `sub` to make the values accessible throughout the calling page?

Comment: It will be variable scope, use `Option Explicit` and `Dim` to make sure that all your variables are declared and scoped correctly. What I mean by scope is for example if you have have variables declared using `Dim` inside a `Sub` procedure they will only be available inside that procedure. To make them available outside the procedure declared them outside using `Dim`. This is also Unknown as globally defining variables. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23909972/692942) for my information on variable declaration and scope.

Comment: thank you for your patient answer!

Comment: @Lankymart - if you will, enter your response as the answer, i will check it off.

Comment: Such values are usually stored as Application Variables, which get global scope by their very definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here will be the scope of the variable.

Take this example, we have a one variable called `testvar` but it's defined in two different scopes, the first is in the Global Scope and the second is in the Local Scope of a Sub Procedure.

```vb
Option Explicit
'Variable declared in the global scope will be available to any procedure
'wishing to use it.
Dim testvar: testvar = "global"

Call Test()
Call Test2()
Call Response.Write(testvar & "<br />") 'Will equal "global changed"

Sub Test()
  Call Response.Write(testvar & "<br />") 'Will equal "global"
  'Updating the global variable.
  testvar = "global changed"
End Sub

Sub Test2()
  'Variable declared in the local scope and will only be available
  'to the procedure it is declared in.
  Dim testvar: testvar = "local"
  Call Response.Write(testvar & "<br />") 'Will equal "local"
End Sub
```

Output:

```
global
local
global changed
```

Where this could get confusing is when the `testvar` declarations are not defined correctly causing ambiguity.

Just remember variables declared inside a Sub / Function are only available to that Sub / Function and cannot be used outside the scope of that Sub / Function.

Variables declared outside of a Sub / Function also known as Global Scope *(not always the case if we start talking about Classes, but lets keep it simple for now)* are available to any Sub / Function and can be called anywhere in a page *(including from `#include` as this is just the extension of the existing pages code)*.

---

#### Useful Links

- [What is the difference between Dim and Public in Classic ASP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23909972/692942)